# Postman/JavaScript/API: Check if string contains dates and convert into time stamp

Tags: javascript, json, api, timestamp, postman

I am completely new to the topic of APIs and Postman and have the following question:
How can I detect multiple dates in a string and reformat them into a timestamp?

I pulled a JSON format via an API, then converted it to a string via the JSON.stringify function, and then stored it in an environment variable.

It now looks something like this:

```
[{“date”:“2000-01-01”,“value”:11.8432},{“date”:“2001-01-01”,“value”:112.2348},{“date”:“2002-01-01”,“value”:182.3777},{“date”:“2003-01-01”,“value”:15.0186},{“date”:“2004-01-01”,“value”:131.3781},{“date”:“2005-01-01”,“value”:145.3683}]
```

Now I’m trying to get this string back into a JSON format but I’d like to add a UNIX time stamp to the date (in milliseconds since January 1, 1970).

So it should look something like this:

```
[{“date”:946684800000,“value”:11.8432},{“date”:978307200000,“value”:112.2348},{“date”:1009843200000,“value”:182.3777}…
```

Does anyone know how to solve this within Postman (JavaScript for Postman)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use moment library and the valueOf() method:

```
moment = require('moment')

let date = [{ "date": "2000-01-01", "value": 11.8432 }, { "date": "2001-01-01", "value": 112.2348 }, { "date": "2002-01-01", "value": 182.3777 }, { "date": "2003-01-01", "value": 15.0186 }, { "date": "2004-01-01", "value": 131.3781 }, { "date": "2005-01-01", "value": 145.3683 }]


date = date.map((item) => {
    item.date = moment(item.date, "YYYY-MM-DD").valueOf()
    return item
    });

console.log(date)
```

Comment: i removed the item = item step that is not required inside the map function